# Swift: How would you keep the return key disabled in a textfield?

Tags: swift

I am trying to keep the return key disabled / greyed out like it is when .enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true before you start typing. I want to keep it disabled until after the 5th character has been typed. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: The expectation is that validation takes place _when_ the user types Return, not _before_.

Comment: Have you given a shot to my answer @Brett Taylor?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to subclass `UITextField` and override the `hasText` property to match you requirements:

```swift
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override var hasText: Bool { text?.count ?? 0 > 4 }
}
```

And then you just have to use the usual:

```swift
textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true
```

**PS:** Don't forget to assign the new class in the identity inspector if you use Interface Builder.